# Lambda function returns empty payload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a very simple lambda that returns the same event object it receives.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print('json.dumps(event)', json.dumps(event))
    return json.dumps(event)
```

I am invoking it with the following

```
import json
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name = REGION)
response = lambda_client.invoke(
 FunctionName='mylambdafunction',
 InvocationType='Event',
 Payload=json.dumps( {'key111': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'})
)
```

However, when I do response['Payload'].read() I get an empty bytestring b'' back. Does anyone know what might be the issue? I can see the in the logs the function is receiving the event and attempts to return it, but all I get is that empty byte string no matter what I return payload comes back empty (it is a botocore.response.StreamingBody obj that I apply .read() to).

What is the issue here?

Comment: See InvocationType at [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke). Use 'RequestResponse' for synchronous invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which I resolved the following way:

Your invocation type is declared as 'Event', however as stated in the official documentation (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/invoke.html#invoke) *The API response only includes a status code.*

To effectively get your response payload from the lambda invocation you should declare the invocation type as 'RequestResponse'.

```
InvocationType='RequestResponse'
```

Now *the API response includes the function response and additional data.*